# How do I use join to get a single result searching multiple rows on the join table?

Tags: mysql

I don't really know how to word this but I think an example would make this really easy. Lets say there is a database of students and classes.

```
Students:
id | name
1  | Bill
2  | Tom

Classes
id | name
1  | history
2  | math
3  | science

student_class
student_id | class_id
1          | 1
1          | 3
```

What I'm trying to do is get the query to return student Bill ONLY IF I search for classes 1 AND 3, right now I can get it to return Bill if I search for 1, 1 and 3, and 1, 2, and 3 using a normal left join. I'm trying to search from the students table and find results that only include all search terms listed. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM students
LEFT JOIN studen_classes on students.id = student_classes.student_id
WHERE student_classes.class_id IN (1,3)
```

I've also tried

```
WHERE student_classes.class_id = 1 AND student_classes.class_id = 3
```

They both will return results if a student is attached to class 1 OR 3 when I want the results to only return students who have class 1 AND 3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `HAVING` clause in there, with appropriate `GROUP BY` and whatnot:

```
HAVING COUNT(student_class.class_id) = 2
```

That'll post-filter the query results to allow only those records where the count of class ID's is 2, meaning that they're in both the `1` and `3` classes. If they're in only one of the two, or none, their count would be 0 or 1.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it will only work if s/he is looking to satisfy all requirements, i.e. 1 and 2, if s/he is looking for someone that did 1 and 2 or 3 and 4 and 5, it won't work

Comment: Yes, but if you're looking for classes 1,3 then `WHERE class_id IN (1,3)` will return only those students in EITHER class, and the having clause will further filter to only those that are in BOTH

Comment: I upvoted you, don't get me wrong, I just want the OP to understand that the solution is limited, not that I think there is a ``quicker`` way, or a ``nicer`` one. To do a more generic solution would require an elaborate SQL and/or code